# 403 Forbidden Error for HubConnection.StartAsync() Method with active Azure AD Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-web-app-service, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on a chat application in Blazor and C#. The sample is really similar to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9bA8elRULI

After deploying it to an Azure App Service everything works fine. If i turn on Azure AD authentication with Microsoft as an identity provider and an app registration i get an error. See browser dev tools.

[Error in browser dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9c8E.png)

Here is how i start my HubConnection:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chatservice")).Build();

hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
{
    userMessages.Add(new UserMessage { Username = user, Message = message, isCurrentUser = user == usernameInput, DateSent = DateTime.Now });

    this.InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
});

await hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

The error occurs in the last line `hubConnection.StartAsync();`

Hint: it´s not an option to turn off the authentication

Comment: Hint: [Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: In short Signalr can use many transport methods to get its job done (sockets, long polling etc). You need to handle the pipeline to make sure the credentials make it the hub. The link Dimitris provided covers this.